# CheckBox .isChecked() not accessing code

Tags: android, android-intent, android-checkbox

I'm using a checkbox on an activity to determine what List needs to have the object added to it.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String intentFlag = i.getStringExtra("flag");

if(listFlag.isChecked() && intentFlag == "main"){
    newProduct.put("shoppingList", true);
    newProduct.put("mainList", true);
} else if (listFlag.isChecked() && intentFlag == "shoppingList"){
    newProduct.put("mainList", true);
    newProduct.put("shoppingList", true);
} else if (!listFlag.isChecked() && intentFlag == "main"){
    newProduct.put("mainList", true);
    newProduct.put("shoppingList", false);
} else if (!listFlag.isChecked() && intentFlag == "shoppingList"){
    newProduct.put("mainList", false);
    newProduct.put("shoppingList", true);
}
```

At the moment, the only `intentFlag` that can be returned from the `Intent` is `"main"`, however, code within the IF statement is never reached. Looking at the Debug, it's returning "main"

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java you should compare strings using `equals()`, not `==`. So it should be:

```
if(listFlag.isChecked() && intentFlag.equals("main")){
   ....
```

or to avoid potential [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html), safer form (in case `intentFlag` is `null`) would be:

```
if(listFlag.isChecked() && "main".equals(intentFlag)){
   ...
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot. Been a long day. Thanks for your help, will accept as answer when it lets me